# Monitoring file creation in OneDrive using a Python Azure Function

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I've have been trying to explore and learn azure functions. This is my first exposure to azure and a little bit of a struggle getting started. I have a OneDrive trigger in my logic app which successfully returns the content of text file.

[image]

Next I am trying to have the azure function read out the content of the text file as an http response. Eventually, I would like to be able to have my function email out .html charts I make in python, but right now I am just trying to get the basics down. Unfortunately, it is reading out the default message when an azure function is created??? This is despite the fact I've made and deployed and am using a custom function.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I can confirm that I am pointing to the correct deployed function. but maybe I am not linking the trigger to azure function correctly? I am at a loss. If anyone could suggest resources to learn azure functions w/ python examples that would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the flow we can able to understand that you are going in the right way. But when I tried to reproduce the same with code you've provided I am receiving an Internal 500 error as the trigger is using the content of the uploaded files which is of .txt format and you are using the same content to extract HTML charts.
[image]

This might be due to the fact that you aren't deploying the function in the right way, That's the reason why you are receiving a default message. You can find the whole procedure in the portal itself. It might take some time to deploy but you can able to see a message when the function is deployed in Visual studio.
[image]

For more information you can refer [azure-functions · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/azure-functions/) and [GitHub - Azure-Samples/functions-docs-python: Python samples that support Azure Functions docs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/functions-docs-python).